# Deleting characters from permutations and character combinations

Tags: linux, bash

To delete particular characters from a combination list.

```
printf "%s\n" {a..c}{a..d} | sed 's/^cc//' | tr -s '\n'
```

I used the code above to delete a particular line of character from combination. Is there a way I can do it without sed, awk, grep or bc. Can I get it done with a single line of code in the script?

Comment: `Is there a way I can do it without sed, awk, grep or bc.` Yes, you can use perl, python, c, c++, java... _what_ do you _want_ to use instead? `Can I get it done with a single line of code in the script?` You posted a single line of code, so yes, you can, it's right there in your post. Anyway, instead of replacing the line with `cc` with empty and then squeezing newlines, just remove the line in sed -  `sed '/^cc/d'`

Comment: The whole code is on linux bash. I'm trying to do it without sed, awk, grep or bc and just a single line of code probably with printf or tr

Comment: Your input is unclear whether you use `{a..c}{a..d}` as an example if it’s your "true" input. Also, the notion of "one line" is meaningless in almost any programming language since you can add as many instructions as you want using separators (e.g. `;` in Bash). At last, your exclusion of sed, awk, grep and bc is awkward at best. It could mean that you want to avoid those programs specifically, or that you want to avoid all programms whatsoever (hence you need to use "pure" bash instructions).

Comment: @vdavid yes I want to use pure bash instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have stored your values in an array, e.g.:

```sh
arr=({a..c}{a..d})
```

Then you may filter your array elements with a string substitution:

```sh
printf -- '%s\n' "${arr[@]/%cc/}"
```

The syntax `${arr[@]/%cc/}` tells to parse all elements from the array `arr` and substitute `%cc` with nothing. The `%` character indicates the beginning of the string, similar to `^` in `sed`, thus `%cc` means "every string beginning with cc".

Comment: The idea is to put everything in one line and still give me the result intended

Comment: `arr=({a..c}{a..d}) ; printf -- '%s\n' "${arr[@]/%cc/}"`